# Pipe or echo password into RAR command?

Tags: macos, bash, shell, rar

I'm trying to use RAR from the command line on a password protected archive:

```
$ rar t spe_05_1.part13.rar

RAR 5.11   Copyright (c) 1993-2014 Alexander Roshal   27 Aug 2014
Trial version             Type RAR -? for help

Enter password (will not be echoed) for spe_05_1.part13.rar:
```

RAR does not appear to have a password switch. It does offer a way to set a password on an archive, but I can't find a way to pass the password to the command for testing (`t` command) or extraction (`x` command):

```
$ rar | grep -i password
  hp[password]  Encrypt both file data and headers
  p[password]   Set password
  p-            Do not query password
```

I need to automate entering the password (I have to try multiple passwords), so I am trying to use `echo` and `pipe`:

```
$ echo diespe120 | rar t spe_05_1.part13.rar

RAR 5.11   Copyright (c) 1993-2014 Alexander Roshal   27 Aug 2014
Trial version             Type RAR -? for help

Enter password (will not be echoed) for spe_05_1.part13.rar:
```

Unfortunately, that's prompting me.

How do I automate entering a password for RAR in a script?

---

```
PASSWORDS=
for i in {100..150}
do
    pw=$(printf "diespe%03d" $i)
    PASSWORDS+="$pw " 
done

for PASSWORD in $PASSWORDS
do
    echo $PASSWORD | rar t spe_05_1.part13.rar
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
        echo "Password is " $PASSWORD
        break
    fi
done
```

Comment: `7z` is scriptable and supports RAR format I believe.

Comment: Has your rar/unrar no option `-p` to set a password on command line?

Comment: @Cyrus - No, there is no `-p` option (or it does not work as expected). I tried it, but it still prompts. I'm using the RAR provided by Apple on 10.8.5

Comment: @jww Can you provide details on the meaning of "does not work as expected"?  It works fine for me (rar 4.00).

Comment: @John - "does not work as expected" means I was prompted for the password on the command line (and it appear the password was not passed to `rar` through the `-p` option).

Comment: @jww Because computer behavior can depend on the tiniest of details, please show the exact command that you used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How do I automate entering a password for RAR in a script?

To automate, don't use a pipe.  Use a shell variable instead. Try:

```
for PASSWORD in $PASSWORDS
do
    rar t -p"$PASSWORD" spe_05_1.part13.rar
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
        echo "Password is '$PASSWORD'"
        break
    fi
done
```

Comment: Thanks John. I was not able to get RAR to accept the password with `-p`. But I was able to do it with [7z](http://www.macports.org/ports.php?by=library&substr=p7zip) from MacPorts as suggested by tripleee.